# Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH correctly

Tags: environment-variables, libraries, matlab, boost

I am using Docker with image of Ubuntu 16.04. I am using this docker to run:

- Import C++ classes in python with the help of boost.python
- Import matlab's python package in python with the help Matlab Runtime (MCR).

Before I have installed MCR in the docker, I have installed boost using:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y libboost-all-dev
```

and I was able to wrap C++ classes and call them in python. Then I have installed MCR and one of the requirement is to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to Matlab's library.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/extern/bin/glnxa64
```

It worked, I was able to run matlab's python package in python but testing the C++ classes wrappers failed due to change of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. For example, I get the following error when I try to import C++ class in python:

```
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1.0: undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt
```

If I unset `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` C++ import works but MCR fails. So the question what `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should be in order to run both C++ classes and Matlab's python package successfully?

I have tried to add path to boost libraries to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but didn't work, so the env value would be:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/extern/bin/glnxa64
```

**EDIT**

the dependencies of C++ library file before setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcee0dc000)
    libpython3.4m.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 (0x00007f9d69e59000)
    libboost_python-py34.so.1.55.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so.1.55.0 (0x00007f9d69c09000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f9d698fe000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9d695fd000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9d693e7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9d6903c000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f9d68e34000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f9d68c0b000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f9d689f0000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9d687d3000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9d685cf000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f9d683cc000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9d6a6c3000)
```

After setting `the LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc42e9b000)
    libpython3.4m.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 (0x00007fad9635b000)
    libboost_python-py34.so.1.55.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so.1.55.0 (0x00007fad9610b000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fad95d8a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fad95a89000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/sys/os/glnxa64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fad95873000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fad954c8000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fad952c0000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/bin/glnxa64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fad95095000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fad94e7a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fad94c5d000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fad94a59000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fad94856000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fad96bc5000)
```

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH should be avoided in favor of binaries that set the RUNPATH internally in the ELF header.

Comment: @schily I am sorry, can you elaborate more on this, I am very confused with `RUNPATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Is there a way to set `RUNPATH` for matlab MCR without the need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: If you have the standard ELF utilities installed, you could run `dump -Lv binaryfile` to get the related information. If you only have the GNU tools, you need to check the related man pages. `RUNPATH` is created in the ELF header with the `-R` option from the linker and tells the runtime linker where to look for shared libraries that are specific to that binary.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting downvoted - aside from the fact that it's arguably up to Mathworks to distribute their application in a way that doesn't require such hackery. You may find some of the discussion here relevant: [MATLAB bindings, when installed, do not work](https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/244)

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for your support. I really hate it when people downvote without pointing out what is the problem. Anyway, thanks for the link I will have a look at it

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a weird question, but do you need both of these things to work at the same time (i.e. you run one command and both dependencies are needed) or are you able to run these things separately (i.e. you could run `var=whatever command` to launch a command with a certain var set without setting it for the whole session) ... If the latter, then you could make a `.sh` script that runs the command that needs the variable with `var=whatever` in front of it and not have it set the rest of the time.

Comment: `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: @mikserve I have tried to set the env for each run but the web framework (python's Django) would still capture the environments pre to the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way it worked for me is by defining `LD_PRELOAD` and point it to system library. So my current environment would be:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/extern/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/sys/opengl/lib/glnxa64
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so
```

So in docker, I have created a `.matlab` file that contains the mentioned env variables. Then, in dockerfile I added the following:

```
services:
  django: &django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - shared_upload_tmp:/app_temp
      - media:/app/computation_server/media
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
      - ./.envs/.production/.matlab
    ports:
      - "8800:8000"
    command: /start
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a couple of options:

1. Prefix the path to your shared libraries in the `export` statement above (more than likely `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set on your system and so the only paths that are getting set are the ones explicitly set in your export statement.)

   ```
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/:/usr/lib/:/usr/lib64/:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/extern/bin/glnxa64
   ```

   This `export` statement will not be a permanent part of your shell sessions unless you add it to `.bashrc` fyi.
2. Add the MATLAB library path to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` and run `ldconfig` to identify the new paths for the linker on your system.

   (BTW I am guessing at the `MATLAB` library name. You might need to make the name of the file something other than `MATLAB` like all lower case or something else. Basically we need the name of the library as it is referenced during the linking process. You could inspect a make file to see how this is referenced.)

   ```
    # Add the file '/etc/ld.so.conf.d/MATLAB' with the following lines 
    /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/runtime/glnxa64
    /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/bin/glnxa64
    /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/sys/os/glnxa64
    /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/extern/bin/glnxa64
   ```

   Then run ldconfig.

   ```
    sudo ldconfig
   ```

   You may need to unset the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable to make the linker use the normal system search path and pickup the new search path for MATLAB.

   ```
    unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I will test what have you suggested and let you know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Your answer was the closest answer I didn't get it to work yet but I think I am getting there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues on my workstation. To get around that, I had created a folder under this path `/usr/lib/GLops`, then I extracted the `GL libraries` from the [Mesa
rpms](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=mesa) and put them in that directory.  Finally, I added the following lines to `~.tcshrc`

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib64/GLops/libGL.so
setenv LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE 1
setenv LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT 1
setenv LIBGL_DIR3_DISABLE 1
setenv MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE 2.1
```

The path `/usr/lib64/GLops/` contain the following files:

```
libGL.so  libGL.so.1  libGL.so.1.2.0  libxcb.so  libxcb.so.1  libxcb.so.1.1.0
```

The libs I have in `/usr/lib64/GLops:/usr/lib/GLops`